# Cannot run quake 3 engine compiled from source code

Tags: quake3

Recently I tried to compile and run the source code of Quake 3 engine. I basically followed [this](http://my.opera.com/fredrikluo/blog/compiling-quake-3) article. However it doesn't work for me.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7, with June 2010 DirectX SDK (I doubt if it is necessary). Here is how I did:

1. Install the original version of Quake 3 Arena to "D:\Quake III Arena", and update to 1.32
2. Download and extract the source code
3. Open `quake3.sln` in "`code`" folder. Visual Studio upgraded it to 2010 format.
4. Build all the 8 projects in Debug mode (in some order). I checked that every project had been built successfully
5. In the properties of quake3 project, in Debugging page, I changed "Working Directory" to "`$(TargetDir)`" and "Command Arguments" to "`+set fs_cdpath "D:\Quake III Arena"`"
6. Set quake3 as the Startup Project and press F5

The game started and could correctly recognize the game folder and parse some options, such as screen resolution. However an exception window popped out before I can see the game main menu, saying "Unhandled exception at 0x053e9938 in quake3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation."

I tried to start the game from command line, but it had the same problem.

I followed the code and found that the exception was generated in `int VM_CallCompiled(vm_t *vm, int *args)`, when executing `call entryPoint` in the `__asm` block, located in line 1148 of vm_x86.c. Since it's assembler code, I don't know how to debug it.

I don't know if anyone here knows about this problem. Could anyone provide some help on this? Thanks gratefully.

Comment: Callstack? Look at the parameters of the functions, this might give you an idea. Looks like a NULL pointer access, look where this pointer is coming from.

Comment: Correction: not a NULL pointer, I was reading 0x00000005, however, did you run a debug build or release build? Try to build a debug build if you didnt do it yet.

Comment: Can you write the call stack?, this window can be 
shown in Debug->Windows->Call Stack

Comment: This is probably an error inside the Q3VM, which is a byte code interpreter/JIT. Can you rebuild the game code as DLL:s instead of Q3VM and run that? vm_cgame 0, vm_game 0 and vm_ui 0 in your config to use native DLL:s instead of byte code.

Comment: @MaikSemder   As I said in the post, I built in Debug mode

Comment: @momboco My call stack is like   05299938() 
> quake3.exe!VM_Call(vm_s * vm, int callnum, ...)  Line 702 + 0xd bytes C
  quake3.exe!CL_InitUI()  Line 1163 + 0xd bytes C
  quake3.exe!CL_StartHunkUsers()  Line 2164 C
  quake3.exe!Com_Init(char * commandLine)  Line 2498 C
  quake3.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)  Line 1212 + 0xa bytes C
  quake3.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 275 + 0x2c bytes C
  quake3.exe!WinMainCRTStartup()  Line 189 C  05299938 is the value of entryPoint. Sorry for the format, I don't know how to handle it :(

Comment: @void Yes, I can see the main menu after adding the three parameters. However, the game crashed in the same place when I tried to start a round of game. Thanks, but do you have any further clues?

Comment: @void Ah, I figured out, I have to add another parameter `+set sv_pure 0`. It was inspired from some comments in `unix\ChangeLog`. Thank all the people here.

Comment: You could possibly be missing a file. I got this error a bunch of times when trying to build the engine and it was a missing file. Pretty weird!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `+set sv_pure 0 +set vm_game 0 +set vm_cgame 0 +set vm_ui 0` in the command line argument.